# Youtube video not playing in landscape mode in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, video, youtube, ios8

My app consist a functionality of playing videos both in landscape and portrait mode.videos can be youtube also everything was working fine till iOS 7 but now youtube videos are not working in landscape mode on iOS 8.

my code:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)applicationsupportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {


  if ([[window.rootViewController presentedViewController]
     isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]] || [[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController")])        {

      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
  } else {

      if ([[window.rootViewController presentedViewController]
         isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {

          // look for it inside UINavigationController
          UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController *)[window.rootViewController presentedViewController];

          // is at the top?
          if ([nc.topViewController isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

            // or it's presented from the top?
          } else if ([[nc.topViewController presentedViewController]
                    isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
              return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
          }
      }
  } 

  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Everything was working fine till iOS 7 but stop working on iOS 8.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well its sometimes silly to answer your own question but its good to help others who are facing the same problem.

in iOS 8 instead of checking for MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController we need to check for AVFullScreenViewController. So below is the complete method for all iOS versions i.e iOS 8 and less.

```
 - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)applicationsupportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

  if ([[window.rootViewController presentedViewController]
     isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]] || [[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController")] || [[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"AVFullScreenViewController")]) {

      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
  }else {

      if ([[window.rootViewController presentedViewController]
         isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {

          // look for it inside UINavigationController
          UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController *)[window.rootViewController presentedViewController];

          // is at the top?
          if ([nc.topViewController isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
              return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

              // or it's presented from the top?
          } else if ([[nc.topViewController presentedViewController]
                    isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
              return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
          }
      }
  }

  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

**Update :**
Works in iOS 9 as well

Comment: upvoted cuz answering your own question isn't silly. unanswered stack posts are silly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm having trouble making it work on iOS7 - details are too big for a comment, made a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443485/fullscreen-video-screen-is-not-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-on-ios7-device

Comment: Thank you for this! The rotation is working as intended when the video view is active. I'm having an issue where after I tap the done button while the app is in landscape mode, the app returns to portrait mode but the navigation bar doesn't resize properly. The height of the navigation bar is less than it should be.

Comment: @WilliamChen well i don't have any idea why the height of your navigation bar is reducing. May be asking a separate question will get help from others.

Comment: Hi can we do this without adding code in app delegate? Thanks!

Comment: please corect "applicationsupportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow" to "application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow"

Answer (score 5):

I have similar code in my app, which also broke in iOS8.

I just wanted to post my version of this fix in case it helps anyone.

The main difference is, i'm only checking against the top most presented controller.

I think this makes more sense than the nested conditionals trying to figure out what kind of vc is presenting another vc.

Anyway, I've got this in my app delegate, and it's working great in 8.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    id presentedViewController = [self topMostController];

    if ( [self vcIsVideoPlayer:presentedViewController] ) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}

- (UIViewController*) topMostController {
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

    return topController;
}

- (BOOL) vcIsVideoPlayer:(UIViewController *)vc {
    NSString *className = vc ? NSStringFromClass([vc class]) : nil;
    return (
            [className isEqualToString:@"MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController"] ||
            [className isEqualToString:@"MPMoviePlayerViewController"] ||
            [className isEqualToString:@"AVFullScreenViewController"]
            );
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly but when the video stops playing the underlying view controller is presented in landscape!

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Update**:
One thing to add if you notice your status bar breaking after you come back to your controller from a landscape video is to set the status bar as not hidden to false in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

```
   override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: .None)
}
```

For those in Swift, a few additional notes. This method (`application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow`) should be in your AppDelegate class or whatever you've set to `@UIApplicationMain`. In order to have access to the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` class, you must remember to `import MoviePlayer`.

Second, the `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` value is not compatible with the Swift version of the delegate by itself, so you need to access `rawValue` and transform the resulting `Uint` into an `Int`. Here is the Swift solution for those in need.

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow) -> Int {
    var orientation =  UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait

    if let presentedController = window.rootViewController?.presentedViewController {

        //check for the controllers
        if presentedController is MPMoviePlayerViewController ||
           presentedController.isKindOfClass( NSClassFromString("AVFullScreenViewController").self ) ||
           presentedController.isKindOfClass( NSClassFromString("MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController").self ) {
           orientation = .AllButUpsideDown
        }
        //otherwise, we may be inside a Nav.
        //safely get the nav controller otherwise ignore this block
        else if let navController = presentedController as? UINavigationController {

            if navController.topViewController is MPMoviePlayerViewController ||
               navController.topViewController.isKindOfClass( NSClassFromString("AVFullScreenViewController").self )  ||
               navController.topViewController.isKindOfClass( NSClassFromString("MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController").self ) {
               orientation = .AllButUpsideDown
            }
        }


    }

   return  Int(orientation.rawValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution in Swift tested on iOS7 and iOS8. You have to add this method to your AppDelegate class.

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {

    var topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController

    if (topController != nil) {
        while ((topController!.presentedViewController) != nil) {
            topController = topController!.presentedViewController;
        }

        if (topController != nil && (topController!.className == "AVFullScreenViewController" || topController!.className == "MPFullScreenTransitionViewController"))  {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue);
        }

    }

    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue);
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:  Objective-C method 'application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:' provided by method 'application(_:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'application(_:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:)' in protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'. Is there anything else you have to do to implement this code?

Answer (score 0):

I could not detect the `AVFullScreenViewController` in my app on iOS 8 Golden Master, but finding `AVPlayerView` does the trick.

UIViewController+VideoAutorotate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController (VideoAutorotate)

@end
```

UIViewController+VideoAutorotate.m

```
#import "UIViewController+VideoAutorotate.h"

BOOL testAnyViewRecursively(UIView *view, BOOL (^test)(UIView *view)) {
    if (test(view)) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
            if (testAnyViewRecursively(subview, test)) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}

@implementation UIViewController (VideoAutorotate)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if (UI_PAD) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        // iOS 6: MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController in iOS 6 doesn't seem to override this method to return YES.
        if ([NSStringFromClass([self class]) isEqual:@"MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController"]) {
            return YES;
        }
        // iOS 8:
        return testAnyViewRecursively(self.view, ^BOOL(UIView *view) {
            return [NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqual:@"AVPlayerView"];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you couldn't detect AVFullScreenViewController because you are introspecting views as opposed to view controllers.

Comment: When I tried to find `AVFullScreenViewController`, use `[self class]` like lines for iOS 6 in my code.

Comment: @Rajat Thanks for collecting some spelling and grammar, but I mean GM is "Golden Master" not GSM (Global System for Mobile communications).

Comment: @hiroshi Thanks for correcting me. As for your comment GSM is now updated to Golden Master.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Swift 3 version for iOS 10.1. I've modified Anthony Persaud answer here. To check `if presentedController.isKind(of: MPMoviePlayerViewController.self)`, you'll need `import MediaPlayer` at the top.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    if let presentedController = window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController,
        let avFullScreen = NSClassFromString("AVFullScreenViewController").self,
        let mpInlineVideoFullscreen = NSClassFromString("MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController").self {

        if presentedController.isKind(of: MPMoviePlayerViewController.self) ||
            presentedController.isKind(of: avFullScreen) ||
            presentedController.isKind(of: mpInlineVideoFullscreen) {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.allButUpsideDown
        }
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait

}
```