# Rotate when enters a video in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsnotificationcenter

I had this code implemented in iOS 7 and worked perfectly, but in iOS 8 it doesn't work

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeStarted:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeFinished:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

-(void)youTubeStarted{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying = YES;
}

-(void)youTubeFinished{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying = NO;
}
```

I've tried changing UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification to MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification. With no luck

Any way else to do this?

**EDIT**

Look what happens I think with iOS 8.1, using the answer of NorthBlast. It worked perfectly with iOS 8.0 & iOS 8.0.2

[image]

Comment: please let me know if you find an answer/solution for this.. I'm exactly with the same problem

Comment: @NorthBlast have you found a solution? Still having the same problem

Comment: yah, I did but not for the WillExit.. I have one that works as DidExit.. I will post it..

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561812/uimovieplayercontrollerdidenterfullscreennotification-not-work-in-ios8

Comment: I think the problem you are having now is with layout issues and not with the notifications but I will check it tonight..

Comment: @NorthBlast this made it worked again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967615/youtube-video-not-playing-in-landscape-mode-in-ios-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this is a solution, I am using for now.. I check first which OS is running the device and then use the appropriate NSNotificationCenter for it :)

```
#define IS_OS_6_OR_LATER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0)
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)

if(IS_OS_6_OR_LATER){

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeStarted:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeFinished:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

}

if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeStarted:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification object:self.view.window];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeFinished:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification object:self.view.window];

}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I am getting the same mistake as @ElioMB , what can we do here ?

Comment: I tried it,  it woks !
but how to lock other viewcontroller's orientation