# Set orientation of MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

My whole application is in portrait mode only and i am playing youtube video in my application. For you tube I am using UIWebview. When user click on play button in UIWebview it automatically launch the MPMoviePlayerController. So I did not declared any MPMoviePlayerController object. So I want MPMoviePlayerController support both portrait and landscape orientation. So please suggest.

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967615/youtube-video-not-playing-in-landscape-mode-in-ios-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `NavigationController`, you could subclass it and do the following:

```
#import "MainNavigationController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@implementation MainNavigationController

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[[self.viewControllers lastObject] presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }

}
@end
```

Then you should set your app to support all orientations, and this code will allow orientation change only if it is playing your movie 'MPMoviePlayerController`.

When calling your `movie` you should send a notification, so if user closes it in any orientation other than `portrait`it switches back to `portrait`.

Something like this:

```
- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.player.moviePlayer];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:videoUrl];

    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    self.player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.player]; 
}

-(void)moviePlaybackDidFinish
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
     [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
                                forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

This should do it for you, let me know how it goes.